# how Convert char[] of numbers to integer number?

Tags: c, char, int

Suppose I have:

```
Operand[2][4] = {{"1", "2", "3", "4"},{"5", "6", "7", "8"}};
```

and I have some bit variables called Operand1_sign and Operand2_sign (0: positive and 1: negative) suppose they are:

```
Operand1_sign = 0;
Operand2_sign = 1;
```

How can I convert this into 2 integers and apply some operation on them (such as summation)

i.e.

```
signed int Operand1, Operand2, Result;
```

so finally I can get the following:

```
Operand1 = + 1234;
Operand2 = - 5678;
Result = Operand1 + Operand2;
```

Comment: int atoi (const char * str) ?, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: I didn't notice that you'd included the 'homework' tag. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is just a small part of project on PIC18

Comment: @Tong: How can I enter Operand[][] as a parameter of atoi() ? Sorry, I'm used to JAVA and I'm new at C :)

Comment: BTW, `atoi` will fail since the `Operand` values aren't 0-terminated. It would work if you had `char Operand[2][5] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'},{'5', '6', '7', '8', '\0'}};`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: NO, as @Joce just said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_atoi(char* operand, int bufsize, int sign)
{
    char* value = new char[bufsize+1];
    memcpy(value, operand, bufsize);
    value[bufsize] = '\0';
    int ret = 0;
    sscanf(value, "%d", &ret);
    if (sign < 0)
    {
        ret = -ret;
    }
    delete [] value;
    return ret;
}

void main()
{
    char Operand[2][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4'},{'5', '6', '7', '8'}};
    signed int Operand1 = my_atoi(Operand[0], 4, 1);
    signed int Operand2 = my_atoi(Operand[1], 4, -1);
    signed int Result = Operand1 + Operand2;
}
```

However, I would definitely recommend you get your strings as null terminated strings. In that case, you could skip the manual implementation of my_atoi, and just do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char Operand[2][5] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'},{'5', '6', '7', '8', '\0'}};
    signed int Operand1 = atoi(Operand[0]);
    signed int Operand2 = -atoi(Operand[1]);
    signed int Result = Operand1 + Operand2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of answering, I'll give you a clue: the number `1234` can also be expressed as `1 * 1000 + 2*100 + 3*10 + 4*1` - this is the key to parsing numbers :)

Comment: But this technique seems to be working only on fixed length-arrays. In my project, at every time I have different inputs so the array won't be fixed (actually it has maximum 13)

Comment: This works on non-fixed length arrays too with a bit of cleverness - you're right that you can't directly apply this

Comment: @Eng.Fouad you never mentioned that Operand could be of variable size in your question.

Comment: I was looking for converting char[] to int, and I said it's OK I could apply it on variable size of array

Comment: "Suppose I have: `Operand[2][4]`". That's pretty much fixed. Also, I would really avoid doing the parsing yourself. There are functions in the standard library for that already.